# Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core

I have been dealing with this problem for about a week now. Can anyone help.

I tried installing System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0.0.0 thought Nuget but it didnt work

this is my code btw

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask {
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance) {
        Console.WriteLine("Running demo with WebListener.");
        IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .Build();
        IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<WebHost>()
            .UseWebListener(options => {
                options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
            });
        IWebHost host = builder.Build();
        host.Run();
    }
}
class WebHost {
    private int m_hight = 720;
    private int m_width = 1080;
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
        app.Run(async (context) => {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("hello there");

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of .Net Core do you use?

Comment: I created a background application by Visual Studio 2017, added your code into my project, and installed AspNetCore related packages, but the project can not build successfully with errors such as ***"'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder' is not a valid Windows Runtime parameter type."*** Could you tell me how did you create the project?And when did the exception throw, installing the package or running the application? I can install the System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher 4.0 package and run the app when removing the webhost class.

Comment: Is this an IoT Core application?  you don't mention it anywhere except the tags on the question.  Windows IoT Core has a smaller subset of APIs available.